Sendgrid API connection getting 403 forbidden constantly for both integromat and normal HTTP request
While making a connection to Sendgrid I am not able to connect and the error is 403 forbidden
I tired making normal HTTP request but that is also failing
Please if someone can help me out with it it will be a great help so
API https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/resource
Authorization : Bearer API key


Can you add the curl command (with a redacted API key) with the specific endpoint you try to hit? Also, are you positive that the API key is still valid?

@IObert please check the updated screenshot of postman

You need to type out the command, pics are not accepted for code requests.

@IObert check the image of postman

@easleyfixed check updated

I would assume you are using an invalid or expired API key

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@IObert I have generated fresh full access API key . The fault lies in your system

I'm sorry if you are having issues. It could also be related to local networks. If you believe this is a issue on the side of SendGrid, please open a support ticket as only support has the power to inspect such things.
